# Empty OperationalError: when trying to connect to local PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to connecto to local PostgreSQL database (Windows 10) using psycopg2.

```
con = psycopg2.connect(
  database="postgres", 
  user="postgres", 
  password="*******", 
  host="localhost", 
  port="5432"
)
```

I keep receiving not very informative OperationalError:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-198849577200> in <module>
----> 1 con = psycopg2.connect(
      2   database="postgres",
      3   user="postgres",
      4   password="******",
      5   host="localhost",

~\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    125 
    126     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 127     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    128     if cursor_factory is not None:
    129         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError:
```

Tryed to replace "localhost" by "127.0.0.1" with the same result.
I see the database in psql with 5432 port and the same configuration.
Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Impossible to tell what the error is without any stack trace. Are you sure all the credentials are correct, including your password

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Yes. Doublechecked the credentials with psql... Can you suggest how to trace the stack?

Comment: Try looking at the postgres logs to see what it said happened. You can find them by executing `SHOW log_directory;` in psql.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the log there is an issue: 'FATAL:  unsupported frontend protocol 1234.5679: server supports 2.0 to 3.0' 
Looks like a bug of PostgreSQL 12

Comment: The work around is setting `sslmode="disable"` in psycopg2